# Swift - post data in background once device is connected

Tags: ios, swift, push, offline

I have an app which required the user to post data from a form to a specific endpoint. I need the user to be able to use the app offline. Therefore the idea would be that they could continue to fill out the form as usual, and then once the device is online again the data could be posted to the endpoint in question.

I'm not sure how to handle this in iOS. I don't want to be continually checking for connectivity status if avoidable in the background. Is there a way to queue the task and wait for connection to be established?

Comment: There is always a way. It depends on so many variables, your question is too vague. For example, Firebase Realtime Database has a feature for this built in. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built-in and very feature-rich.

See [Uploading Data to a Website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/uploading_data_to_a_website)
and [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) for full details. (The background doc focuses on downloads, but the same approach work for sending.)

Use `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:)` to create a background session. Then you can use that with URLSessionUploadTask to send your data.

If you need to be launched and informed when the task completes, set `sessionSendsLaunchEvents` (but it sounds like you may not need that).

Use a delegate for callbacks. You can't use completion handlers for this configuration.

For example, to create the session (based on the docs):

```
private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MySession")
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()
```

If you need to be relaunched on completion, you'll also need to configure your app delegate to handle those launch events by implementing:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String,
                 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

(Make sure to call `completionHandler` when you've handed the event!)

See [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063/) from WWDC 2020 for even more details.